# How can I fix 405 error in getTransactionsRelated() TronWeb API?

Tags: blockchain, http-status-code-405

I have used getTransactionsRelated() function in TronWeb API to get all the transactions, but it throws 405 error. Reference: https://developers.tron.network/v3.0/reference#tronwebapi.

Something weird here is that it worked when the api was set up and tested, but dint work the next day(got 405 error).

```
const TronWeb = require('tronweb');
const HttpProvider = TronWeb.providers.HttpProvider;
const fullNode = new HttpProvider(TRON_URL);
const solidityNode = new HttpProvider(TRON_URL);
const eventServer = new HttpProvider(TRON_URL);
const getTransactionHistory = (address, privateKey, offset) => {

    const tronWeb = new TronWeb(
        fullNode,
        solidityNode,
        eventServer,
        privateKey
    );

    const transactions = await tronWeb.trx.getTransactionsRelated(address, "all", 10, offset);

    console.log('transaction', transaction);
}
```

Expected: All transactions of the given address.

Actual: 405 "Method not allowed"

Comment: have you found any solution for the problem? I am running a 400 bad request with the same function even though following the same example given on the documentation.